# Why does an inline function has to be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears?

Tags: c++

There is a rule in the standard [(N4659, dcl.inline/6)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.inline#6):

> If a function or variable with external linkage is declared inline in one translation
> unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required.

(there is a [similar rule in the current draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#dcl.inline-5) standard as well)

Why does this rule use the word "appears"? Instead of "appears", I would have expected that the function/variable need to be odr-used, or some other stronger requirement than "appears". What kind of problems can it cause if an inline function just appears (but otherwise unused) as non-inline in a translation unit?

Note: this issue comes up if one wants to put inline functions into their own separate header to speed up compilation (there are cases when only the class definition is needed, inline function are not). And to make it easy to change `inline`-ness, class definition only contains member function declarations which are not marked inline, and then functions are marked inline at function definition. For example, if I'd like to change a non-inline function to inline, all I need is to move the function from the cpp to the header file and add `inline` to the function definition (no need to edit member function declaration in the class definition - it's one extra place to edit). But the mentioned rule makes this approach invalid.

A concrete example:

Contents of `Foo_def.hpp`:

```
struct Foo {
    void bar(); // note: no inline specifier
};
```

Contents of `Foo_inl.hpp`:

```
#include "Foo_def.hpp"

inline void Foo::bar() { // note: inline is specified here
    // do something useful
}
```

Contents of `a.cpp`:

```
#include "Foo_def.hpp"
#include "Foo_inl.hpp"

void callBar() {
    Foo f;
    f.bar();
}
```

Contents of `b.cpp`:

```
#include "Foo_def.hpp" // note, Foo_inl.hpp is not included

int sizeOfFoo() {
    return sizeof(Foo);
}
```

If both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` is linked in a program, then it is ill-formed according to the cited rule, because `Foo::bar` is an inline function, yet it is not declared as such in `b.cpp`. But this is odd, because `Foo::bar` is not used at all in `b.cpp`, so whether `Foo::bar` is inline or not shouldn't matter.

Comment: This is my mental model : inline is a way to bake in the code into a lib without exposing it to the linker. The moment one of the translation units does have a function that's not inline it will become visible to the linker and it will start affecting other translation units.
Interesting read on inline : https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/inline-hints/

Comment: Since `inline` means "multiple definitions are permitted", all translation units have to agree on that.

Comment: @Eljay Definition or declaration or both?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Static symbols and const variables are neither exposed to the linker. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#internal_linkage https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/tu_local

Comment: @Sebastian • I'm not sure the context of the question.  For examples, If the function declaration specifies `inline` the function definition is implicitly `inline`.  Class member functions and class static functions and class friend functions that are provided *in situ* are implicitly `inline`.  A `constexpr` function is implicitly `inline`.

Comment: It's a consequence of the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) If a function is defined inline and it is defined again but not inline this breaks the ODR exception for `inline` functions.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I think my question is not about that case. I added an example so it should be more clear.

Comment: It would still have to be if;ndr. If a compiler sees only the declaration and ODR-usage, how can it diagnose that an inline definition is missing? It requires a whole view of a program, which diagnosable rules don't require. Under your proposal I think it's easier to have all definitions optimised out by accident, leaving us with a hard to fix unresolved symbol. The current wording makes it less likely to happen (idk if impossible, but definitely less likely).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I'm not sure I follow you. With the current rules, ill-formedness comes from `b.cpp`, where `Foo::bar` is **not** ODR-used, and there is no `Foo::bar` definition available either. Saying that `b.cpp` is well-formed shouldn't change anything practical, compilers can stay exactly the same (as far as I'm aware, my example already works with all major compilers - I see no reason why it shouldn't work).

Comment: Why do you need this relaxation of the rules? What practical problem is it supposed to solve?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Your mental model is incorrect (or perhaps outdated). An inline function has an address, and it is the same address in all TUs. You cannot do that without involving a linker.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. My mental model of an inline function is that it gets written out in the code that "calls" it so it really isn't a function anymore. And what you describe fits better with what my mental model would call a "static" function.  Think I have to double check now :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer You can take an address of an inline function and pass it to another function as a callback for example. If you do, machine code for the function must be generated just as for any non-inline function, and a symbol must be emitted so that the linker can merge the definitions from separate TUs. (It is a special kind of symbol that says to the linker "if you see more than one of these, don't make it a multiple definition error, just merge. I know they must be exactly the same, so take any definition and discard the others".

Comment: FWIW, the wording in N4659 is present in ISO/IEC 14882:1998 7.1.2p4 (So was written before 1998 and was not changed). It might be a standard defect (to change appears -> ODR-used). Or it might be ill-formed for the same reason `extern int x;` `extern void x();` in two different translation units is ill-formed even if neither is used.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. it's only about compile time optimization. But, tbh, I don't really understand the motivation behind the current rule, why is it more strict than necessary (?), hence my question.

Comment: "it's only about compile time optimization" I don't understand what this means in this context. "why is it more strict than necessary" Stricter rules make simpler tools. Making this rule less strict would not solve any actual problem, however you still would need to work hard to make sure that the change is non-breaking. Thus, if someone would bother to formulate a proposal, it would be a very-low priority task.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Putting inline functions into a separate header file makes it possible to include less code: when in a particular translation unit only class definitions are needed, but the definition of inline functions are not. This means that compilation will be faster. So this does solve an actual problem (though admittedly not a large one). I think that relaxing this rule wouldn't cause too much tool complexity increase. On the contrary, it think (most/all?) compilers already accept (and always accepted) my example fine. This is not something that the compiler needs to handle.